# limit of $\frac{x^3y+xy^2}{x^2+y^2}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, limits

find the limit of $$ \lim_{(x,y) \rightarrow (0,0)}\frac{x^3y+xy^2}{x^2+y^2}$$
no idea how to deal with that. I've tried to use squeeze theorem however this attempt was unsuccessful.

Comment: HINT: use polar coordinates $x=r\cos\theta$ and $y=r\sin\theta$.

Comment: I do not want to use polar coordinates as i have little knowledge about that furthermore they are not compulsory in the textbook this was take from.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use AM-GM:
$$
x^2 + y^2 \ge 2|x||y|.
$$
So,
$$
\left|\frac{x^3 y + xy^2}{x^2 + y^2}\right| \le \frac{|xy||x^2 + y|}{2|xy|} = \frac12|x^2 + y|
$$
Now use sandwich theorem.

In polar coordinates
$$
x = r\cos\phi,\quad y = r\sin\phi,
$$
and your limit is
$$
\lim_{r\to 0} \frac{r^4 \cos^3\phi\sin\phi + r^3\cos\phi\sin^2\phi}{r^2} = \lim_{r\to0} r\cos\phi\sin\phi(r\cos^2\phi + \sin\phi),
$$
and
$$
0\le |r\cos\phi\sin\phi(r\cos^2\phi + \sin\phi)| \le r(r+1);
$$
use sandwich again.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a formal proof.

Let $\epsilon \gt 0$.

Choose $\delta = \min \{ 1, \epsilon  \} $

Suppose $ 0 \lt \sqrt{x^2 + y^2}\lt \delta$. Then, $|x|, |y| \le \sqrt{x^2 + y^2} \lt \delta $. Hence, $|y| \le 1$ and $|x| \lt \epsilon$

Now,

$$ \left|{ \frac{x^3y+xy^2}{x^2+y^2} - 0}\right| \le  \frac{|x^3y|+|xy^2|}{x^2+y^2} =  \frac{|x| |y| x^2+|x| y^2}{x^2+y^2} \le \frac{|x| x^2+|x| y^2}{x^2+y^2} \;\; \text{since $|y| \le 1$}  $$

$$ = |x| \lt \epsilon$$

$\mathscr{Q.E.D.}$

Answer (score 0):

Well choosing an arbitrary function $y=f(x)$ should give a feel for what this function might be. Let $y=x$ then we find that $\lim\limits_{(x,y)\to (0,0)}\frac{x^3y+xy^2}{x^2+y^2}=\lim\limits_{(x,x)\to (0,0)}\frac{x^4+x^3}{2x^2}=0$. You should note that if $g(x,y)=\frac{x^3y+xy^2}{x^2+y^2}$ has a limit then it follows that , that limit must be $0$ or other wise this function would approach two different values and the limit wouldn't exist.

Comment: but still this does not answer my question. Picking up two arbitrary functions and showing that the limit will be equal to zero in both cases is pointless, because one can argue that there exists a function that does not give a desired limit when substituted into the functions equation.

Comment: #mkropkowski In this instance I agree with #Nicolas  as changing the coodinates greatly simplifies the problem $\frac{x^3y+xy^2}{x^2+y^2}=\frac{r^4cos^3(\theta)sin(theta)+r^3cos(\theta)sin^2(\theta)}{r^2(cos^2(\theta)+sin^2(\theta))}=r\cos^3(\theta)sin(\theta)+rcos(\theta)sin^2(\theta)$.